# The radical and codim of an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading a commutative algebra book which says, in $k[x,y,t]/(y^2-x^2(t^2-x))$,

1. the radical of the ideal $J=(y^2-x^2(t^2-x),3x^2-2t^2x,2y,2tx^2)$ is $(x,y)$,
2. codim $((y^2-x^2(t^2-x)))=1$.

I don't know how to show them. For (1), since $J$ contains $(2y)$, the radical must contain $(y)$, why is the rest $(x)$? And how can $(x,y)$ generate terms that have $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the four generators of $J$ are contained in the ideal $(x,y)$. So, it suffices to show that $x,y$ are in the radical. As you say, $y$ is clearly in the radical. Last term says $tx$ is in the radical. Then the second term says $x^2$ is in the radical and hence so is $x$.

Comment: Why does the last term say $tx$ is in the radical?

Comment: @DashengWang $(tx)^2=t\cdot tx^2\in J$.

Comment: I see, thanks. May I ask, for the codim, is it $1$ because the only chain of prime ideals in the ring (containing $J$) are $(x)\supset (x,y)$ or $(y)\supset (x,y)$?